# Opening a file in my application from File Explorer

Tags: vb.net, file-extension

I've created my own application in VB.NET that saves its documents into a file with it's own custom extension (.eds).

Assuming that I've properly associated the file extension with my application, how do I actually handle the processing of the selected file within my application when I double click on the file in File Explorer?

Do I grab an argsc/argsv variable in my Application.Load() method or is it something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/VBFileAssociation.aspx) but short answer is `My.Application.CommandLineArgs`